# $x^TAx-b^Tx\leq 0\Rightarrow\|x\|_2\leq\|A^{-1}b\|_2$?

Tags: least-squares

Let $x$ be a vector, $A\succ 0$ an inverse matrix and $b$ a vector with proper dimensions. If $$x^TAx-b^Tx\leq 0,$$ do we have  $$\|x\|_2\leq\|A^{-1}b\|_2?$$

I don't think it's a hard problem, but I cannot think of a proof or a counterexample right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a counterexample, start with any vector $x$ with $\|x\|_2 > \|A^{-1} b\|_2$.  If $x^T A x - b^T x$ happens to be positive, replace $A$ by $-A$ and $b$ by $-b$.

EDIT: I presume you're working over the real numbers, and the added requirement  $A \succ 0$ means $A$ is positive definite (and in particular symmetric).

For a counterexample, take $n=2$,
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 3\cr},\ b = \pmatrix{2\cr 8\cr},\ x = \pmatrix{3.4 \cr 1.7\cr} $$

Comment: Thanks. I was to mean $A\succ 0$, so basically it's a strongly convex function in $x$.

Comment: This is good.Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if considering it as an ellipse, the length of the long radius should be less than $||A^{-1}b||_2$?